# Mocking an object and patching associated functions

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have a simple application that creates a Widget and within that, it creates an Env object. Initializing the Env object requires a lot of external calls that are not necessary for the function I'm testing, so I would just like to mock that object (or init) as a whole. However, I would like to patch the `get_parents` function to return specific data for testing. I cannot figure out how to probably patch this. Here are my classes:

env.py:

```
class Env(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Lots of external calls that are not needed for
        # this specific test
        pass

    def get_parents(self):
        return ['moms']
```

widget.py

```
from env import Env

class Widget(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.env = Env()

    def display_parents(self):
        return ','.join(self.env.get_parents())
```

I'm trying to set up testing to patch the initial object creation and the return values of the function I'm trying to patch. This mocks the object, but does not return the correct values:

tests/test_widget.py

```
@patch('widget.Env.get_parents', return_value=['moms,pops'])
@patch('widget.Env')
def test_widget(mock_env, mock_get_parents):
    widget = Widget()
    assert widget.display_parents() == 'moms,pops' # Fails
```

I tried patching and mocking this way, but the `get_parents` function doesn't even get called:

```
from widget import Widget
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('widget.Env.get_parents', return_value=['moms,pops'])
@patch('widget.Env')
def test_widget(mock_env, mock_get_parents):
    widget = Widget()
    widget.display_parents()
    assert mock_get_parents.called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Env` patch is overriding your `mock_get_parents`.  Just patch `Env` and modify its attributes as appropriate; this is exactly why `Mock` objects are so flexible!

```
@patch('widget.Env')
def test_widget(mock_env_class):
    mock_env_class.return_value.get_parents.return_value=['moms,pops']
    widget = Widget()
    widget.display_parents()
    assert mock_env_class.return_value.get_parents.call_count == 1
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this entire code but it still does not work. It claims that the `call_count` is still 0.

Comment: Oh duh.  Updated my answer.  The trick is that the patch object is the *class*, not an instance -- so its `return_value` is what will be set as `widget.env`.

Comment: This is great! I don't think I would have found this on my own. Thanks!